# Flows and screens - required field conditional

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a screen in a flow in which there are three fields Type, Last Name(Required) and First Name in which Type contains A, B, C options. now i want it like if i choose A or B Last Name and First Name should be Displayed and If i Choose C in Type Field i don't want Last Name and First Name should be Displayed I want entirely other field to displayed 
How to Achieve it?
I want to do it in single screen?

Answer (score 0):

There's been rumors that you'll be able to do this in the future, but the current technology doesn't allow us to do this. You'll necessarily need to have different screens to get the desired effect, including forcing the user to click Next to see the next screen. Otherwise, you'll probably just want to do this in Visualforce, because it will probably take less time and be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired functionality of showing and hiding fields on the screen based on the value of a picklist field, you can use the following approaches:

1. Formula Fields and Conditional Visibility: You can create a formula
   field that evaluates the value of the picklist field, and based on
   the result, set the value of a Boolean variable. Then, you can use
   this Boolean variable to control the visibility of the fields on the
   screen. For example, if the picklist value is "A" or "B", set the
   Boolean variable to "true", which will make the Last Name and First
   Name fields visible. If the picklist value is "C", set the Boolean
   variable to "false", which will hide the Last Name and First Name
   fields and display the other field instead. You can use the
   conditional visibility feature to control the visibility of the
   fields based on the Boolean variable's value.
2. Formula Fields for Dynamic Label and Read-Only Fields: If the above
   approach doesn't work for some reason, you can try using a formula
   field to change the label of the fields dynamically and make the
   unwanted field read-only. For example, you can create a formula
   field that evaluates the value of the picklist field and sets the
   label of the Last Name and First Name fields accordingly. You can
   also use this formula field to make the unwanted field read-only by
   setting its value to a non-editable field value.
3. Custom LWC Component: If the above approaches don't work for your
   needs, you can create a custom LWC component and embed it inside the
   flow. In this approach, you have full control over the functionality
   and can write custom code to achieve the desired behavior.

In conclusion, the first approach of using formula fields and conditional visibility should suffice for most use cases, but if it doesn't, you can use the other approaches mentioned above.

Let me know if anything else is required.

[image: Below is snippet from flow using Approach 1-]